# PUT Method: Not able to send "fileName" form Data using Jersey API using java?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jersey-2.0

following is the code I have written to PUT a image to a jersey server.

```
        byte[] img = image(file);// coverts file into byte strea


    FormDataMultiPart form = new FormDataMultiPart();
    form.field("fileName", file);
    FormDataBodyPart fdp = new FormDataBodyPart("fileUpload",
            new ByteArrayInputStream(img),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    form.bodyPart(fdp);


    ClientResponse rs = wr.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).put(
            ClientResponse.class, form);
```

When I am running the code, i am able to send the byte stream to the server, but its returning error that it is not able to find the filename i am providing in form.field, so returning a 400 bad request error?

i am not able to understand what i am missing here?

Comment: I think somehow I am adding the form data in a wrong way.

Comment: I was doing some more debug and found that form fields are going as below  form = {fileUpload=[com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataBodyPart@3dbd83b2], fileName=[com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataBodyPart@65113ac8]}

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the my problem. I was not adding multipart. This [link](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Multipart-Post-td4252846.html) helped me

Following is what i did to replace the body-part definition

```
    FormDataBodyPart f = new FormDataBodyPart(FormDataContentDisposition
            .name("fileUpload").fileName(file).build(),
            new ByteArrayInputStream(img),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);

    MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart().bodyPart(f);

    ClientResponse rs = wr.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).put(
            ClientResponse.class, multiPart);
```